# Make it out (meaning in a sentence)

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I saw this sentence and I don't understand the use of "make it out" here:
- Felicia, I was wondering if you'd make it out to Hawthorne.

*Is there someone who can explain that to me? And give me some examples?*

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this context, the speaker is talking about Felicia traveling to Hawthorne (correct me if I'm wrong). So then you can break "make it out to Hawthorne" into:

- "make it" meaning "manage to reach" somewhere or something (as in, "we made it!")
- "out to Hawthorne" meaning to the place called Hawthorne, implying that it's pretty out of the way.

If Hawthorne is actually a person, then @Chemomechanics's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To *make out* a document (e.g., a bank check or a note or card) is to designate it to someone (specifically, the recipient) or something. For example, on this past Valentine's Day, my spouse *made out* two cards: one to me and one to my parents. When I need money, I sometimes go to my bank and *make out* a check to "cash."